# Powershell ExecutionPolicy mysteriously resets

Tags: windows-7, powershell, 64-bit

I am well versed in the ways of

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

etc. But for some reason, my machine resets the policy every so often. I have not been able to figure out the pattern, but every week or two I go to run a script and get the dreaded error

```
foo.ps1 is not digitally signed. The script will not execute on the system.
```

Is there any way to audit what might be triggering this?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how to go about tracking/auditing what may be causing it - though it sounds a lot like a group policy object has been set to control that and it is getting refreshed every week or so.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347641.aspx

I would suggest using rsop.msc or gpresult to view the complete set of policies that are being applied. You could also test this theory by issuing a `gpupdate /force` from the command line to force a policy refresh.

Comment: gpupdate /force did not cause the execution policy to revert. I'm on Win7 Home Premium, in a Workgroup, and don't have gpedit.mmc or rsop.mmc. Good theory, though, I really expected gpupdate to cause the issue.

Comment: I was able to set the GP in the registry by inspecting the [ADM](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2917a564-dbbc-4da7-82c8-fe08b3ef4e6d&displaylang=en) in a text editor: HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell, dword EnableScripts=1, string ExecutionPolicy=RemoteSigned. Setting those to 0, AllSigned and running gpupdate /force I was able to break the execution policy, so these reg values do "something." Hopefully this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might check which version of PowerShell is running as well. The policies are different for the 32 and 64 bit versions of PowerShell